# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger

Tags: log4j, slf4j, java-platform-module-system

In my *Java 17* *maven* project I am using *slf4j* based on *log4j2*. It runs fine, when I start it from within *Eclipse*.
*Maven* places the main class in *MANIFEST* of the modules jar file and all dependent jar files in the *target/lib* folder.
*target/lib* hosts the file *log4j-api-3.0.0-alpha1.jar* which hosts the class ***org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger***.

I have check the precense of *org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger* with the *bash* command

```
for i in target/lib/*.jar; do jar -tvf "$i" | grep -Hsi org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger; done
```

When I run my program from the command line with

```
java -p target/lib -m eu.ngong.iqStm
```

I get the failure

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger
        at log4j.slf4j2.impl@3.0.0-alpha1/org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider.initialize(SLF4JServiceProvider.java:53)
        at org.slf4j@2.0.9/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:195)
        at org.slf4j@2.0.9/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:182)
        at org.slf4j@2.0.9/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:490)
        at org.slf4j@2.0.9/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:476)
        at org.slf4j@2.0.9/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:425)
        at org.slf4j@2.0.9/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:451)
        at eu.ngong.iqStm@0.0.2/eu.ngong.iqStm.App.<clinit>(App.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 8 more
```

An idea to narrow the reason why *java* can not find the class *org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger*?

Any idea what I have to add on the command line to run my program?

Answer (score 0):

Since `log4j-slf4j2-impl` in the `alpha1` version is not a full module, the JVM is not able to find its dependencies. You need to add the module for `log4j-api` explicitly:

```
java -p target/lib --add-modules org.apache.logging.log4j -m eu.ngong.iqStm
```

In the next alpha version all modules will be named JPMS modules, so this problem will not appear.